# Time setting for hour

Tags: java, gwt, highcharts

i want to get hours from 18:00 pm to 6:00 am of the next day for each day on the week. How can I get this time for plotBands in GWT/highchart? I want to highlight this nighttime on the charts.

[This is asample in JS](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/NCEM6/), where the date was set from 2 to 4 June and the plotband was drawn. How can I do the same but for getting hours in GWT highcharts?

```
chart.setPlotBands(xaxis.createPlotBand()
                    .setFrom(time.getTime())// how to get here 18:00 pm hour?
                    .setTo(time.getTime())// and here 6:00 am hour?
                    .setColor("#060606"));
```

I tryed it with utc, get nothing, but don't think that is right way:

```
 .setFrom(time.getTime().UTC(2014, 7, 7, 18, 0, 0))
 .setFrom(time.getTime().UTC(2014, 7, 8, 6, 0, 0))
```

I want "mark time x to time y with color z" and get something like on this picture with color for certain time from 18 to 6

[image: demo]

Comment: You should clean up your English here, because what you're asking is very unclear. Set out simply the desired inputs and outputs, what you have tried, and how this is not conforming to your expectation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to highlight a pattern directly with highchart. I made a quick sketch, but did not test the result in GWT/highchart. This method highlights the daily period described by the `int` fields `hourStart` (18 in your example) and `lengthInHours` (12 as per your description):

```
/* 
 * start and end are the lower and upper bounds of your chart data
 *
 */
public void highlightBands(Date start, Date end) {

  Date startDay = toLocalDay(start);
  Date endDay = toLocalDay(end);
  Date current = add(startDay, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -1);

  while (current.before(endDay)) {
    Date bandStart = add(current, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourStart);
    Date bandEnd = add(bandStart, Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, lengthInHours);
    PlotBand band = x.createPlotBand().setFrom(bandStart).setTo(bandEnd);
    x.addPlotBands(band);
    current = add(current, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
  }
}
```

The posted code is a simplified version of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/RaffaeleSgarro/5a3f67567856e5c55185), just to show my approach and without using anything outside `java.util`

Comment: thank you for supporting with answer, what i ment under highlight is only mark this period of time with some color, i hope you understood it that way too, like es in an image. I will try this, thank you

Comment: I think you didn't understand my answer. The provided code computes the bands that you need to add to highchart